# Getting TypeError: control.get is not a function in Angular Unit Testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm writing angular unit test case for password and confirm password validation.

validation.ts file

```
export function matchPasswords(
passwordFieldName: string,
confirmPasswordFieldName: string
): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
const password = control.get(passwordFieldName).value;
const confirmPassword = control.get(confirmPasswordFieldName).value;
if (password !== confirmPassword) {
  control
    .get(confirmPasswordFieldName)
    .setErrors({ passwordsDoNotMatch: true });
  return { passwordsDoNotMatch: true };
} else {
  return null;
}
};
}
```

validation.spec.ts code

```
it('should match both password fields and return null if both matches', () => {
  var passwordField1: string = "Admins@123";
  var confirmPasswordField1: string = "Admins@123";
  const validate = formValidators.matchPasswords(passwordField1, confirmPasswordField1);
   const validate = formValidators.matchPasswords(passwordField1, confirmPasswordField1);
   expect(
     validate({value:{
         'passwordFieldName':passwordField1,
         'confirmPasswordFieldName':confirmPasswordField1}} as AbstractControl)
       .toEqual(null));
 });
```

At the line control.get(passwordFieldName).value I'm getting the error control.get is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to apply your validator to a FormGroup, which will give you access to the FormControls you need. At the moment, you are passing AbstractControl/FormControl, which is a single form field essentially.

Function could look somewhat like this.

```
export function matchPasswords: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const password = fg.get('passwordFieldName').value;
  const confirmPassword = fg.get('confirmPasswordFieldName').value;
  return password === confirmPassword
    ? null
    : { passwordsDoNotMatch: true };
};
```

Comment: I have to write the Unit Test case. I cannot modify the existing TS file code. I have to change only spec.ts file